# Using spatial locator for Oracle

Tags: oracle, spatial

I am able to run the below query but when i swap the parameter for sdo_nn, I get an error of SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index

Works:

```
SELECT
c.customer_id,
c.first_name,
c.last_name,
sdo_nn_distance (1) distance
FROM stores s,
customers c
AND sdo_nn
(c.cust_geo_location, s.store_geo_location, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1)= 'TRUE'
ORDER BY distance;
```

Does not work:

```
SELECT
c.customer_id,
c.first_name,
c.last_name,
sdo_nn_distance (1) distance
FROM stores s,
customers c
AND sdo_nn
(s.store_geo_location,c.cust_geo_location, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1)= 'TRUE'
ORDER BY distance;
```

Anyone can explain to me why the sequence matter?

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle's online docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i78067) `sdo_nn` needs the first parameter to be spatially indexed. the second parameter does not have that necessity/constraint.

So when swapping parameters you need to make sure the "now first" parameter (i.e. `s.store_geo_location`) is spatially indexed. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objindex.htm) on how to create a spatial index in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have both indexed so I don't understand how come it doesn't work when swapped

Comment: @user566375 a spatial index is NOT the same a normal index! the error message clearly says that an index is missing!

Comment: Yes I understand. When i check the validity of the index using command, 

select INDEX_NAME,TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,STATUS,ITYP_OWNER,ITYP_NAME,DOMIDX_STATUS,DOMIDX_OPSTATUS from user_indexes where ITYP_NAME is not null;

It shows that both index are valid

Comment: @user566375 again, that does not prove anything... recreate the index according to the link in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add the compiler hint to tell the query parser what index to use e.g.:

```
select
/*+ index(tableName,sdoIndexName) */
...
```

**WARNING** Compiler hints fail **SILENTLY**